# RouterLink not updating target component after first click

Tags: angular

Angular7, `routerlink` to create a list of item clickable to navigate the corresponding detail page. It works at the first click as expected, but all subsequent click won't update the detail, even their `id` values are unique, detail page not being updated. Fiddler shows no activity after the 1st click.

Routerlink in component:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of Items">
            <td><a routerLink="/itemdetail/{{item.id}}">{{item.id}}</a></td>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = 
                [
                  ...
                  { path: 'itemdetail/:id', component: itemdetail}
                ];
```

itemdetail.ts

```
  id: string;
  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
      this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap)=>
      {
          this.id = params.get('id');
      })
    this.getDetail();  
  }


getDetail(): void
  {
      this.mySvc.getDetail(this.id)
            .subscribe(data => this.items = data);
  }
```

Comment: The component is not reinitializing or in other words the component is being reused. You can check even ngOnDestroy isn’t called. It’s expected behaviour for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngOninit is not called again and again due to component being reused.
Call the function getDetail inside the subscribe, After setting this.id as the subscription to activatedRoute will still be called after every successful navigation.

```js
      id: string;
      ngOnInit(): void 
      {
          this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap)=>
          {
              this.id = params.get('id');
              this.getDetail();  
          })

      }


    getDetail(): void
      {
          this.mySvc.getDetail(this.id)
                .subscribe(data => this.items = data);
      }
```

Comment: moving `this.getDetail()` into the subscribe block is the key!

Answer (score 1):

In your component you haven't used the one-way data binding on the `routerLink` directive to update the links on the fly. Just add square-brackets around `routerLink` directive for the links to update.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let item of Items">
  <td><a [routerLink]="'/itemdetail/' + item.id">{{item.id}}</a></td>
  <!-- other elements -->
</tr>
```

This way your link also updates when the item object changes. Also call your `getDetails()` method inside params subscription, as shown below, so that your item details are updated in the template.

```js
  id: string;
  ngOnInit(): void 
  {
      this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap)=>
      {
          this.id = params.get('id');
          this.getDetail();
      });  
  }
```

I have created a [demo Stackblitz app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g2ewkg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fitems%2Fitem.component.ts) to show the routerLink data binding approach. Click on the `Item page` link in the preview screen to view the demo.

Comment: `[routerLink]` is no need. It's the 2nd part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

might also be a problem of your ngOnDestroy(), mine was.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).